# Why shouldn't I run multiple processes in a Docker container?

Tags: docker

I've been told you should only run a single process within a container. Why can't I run more than one? It looks like I can use supervisord to do this.

Comment: Nothing stopping you from using supervisord within docker. LXC containers were really designed to isolate processes running on a server. Docker has just made the process of building and managing containers more convenient, but hasn't changed their nature. I would advise reading the following article about LXD. Canonical's technology that attempts to make containers behave more like VMs: http://blog.scottlowe.org/2015/05/06/quick-intro-lxd/

Comment: you SHOULD NOT, but you CAN. It is just that a container focusing on one single role will be easier to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I don't think processes generally map well to separation of concerns in a one-to-one fashion.

In fact, I think the best reasoning for recommending running only one process per container today is technical and boils down to process management and logging issues for the most part. These aspects tend to get  messy and complicated when you have more than on process in a container.

Answer (score 1):

Because of `separation of concerns` pattern. It will be easy to upgrade or modify separate containers running separate processes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) or [Honcho](https://blog.codeship.com/using-honcho-create-multi-process-docker-container/) to build multiple processes container.